# Cauchy's Residue Theorem and Cauchy's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

Cauchy's theorem in short says for a holomorphic function $f$ which is holomorphic on and inside a path $\gamma$ the path integral is $0$

I have calculated a path integral around a path where there are three singularities inside- I have Cauchy's Residue Theorem to find the integral- but it has given me $0$- the residues all cancel out. This is perfectly possible right?- the Converse of Cauchy is not necessarily true is it? The integral being $0$ doesn't imply that $f$ is holomorphic on and inside $\gamma$. If it is true- I have made a mistake in arithmetic?

Comment: Take the function $f(z) = {1 \over z^2}$ and the unit circle.

Comment: I see no problem with the residues summing to 0. And no, the converse isn't usually true.

Comment: If the integral vanishes for *every* path on and inside some $\gamma$, then it is holomorphic in the region. That is not the case here. You've shown that it vanishes for just *some* paths.

Comment: Morera's theorem is a sort of converse.

Comment: I understand now- thank you all